# How to make RegExp find the first match only starting from an arbitrary index?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a transpiler from an obscure scripting language(thyme) to javascript, in javascript.

As a whole its far too complex to interpret it through regex alone but being able to use regex would save me a lot of finger stamina.

Heres the situation:

1. I have a source code
2. I have an index which I know is the starting point of the thing I'm trying to capture
3. I want to capture the first occurrence that matches the regexp that I have and the first only as later matches would just be wasting performance without knowing their context at this time.

.

```
var src = "++this is my ++cool source ++code"; 
var idx = 13;
var regex = /(\+\+[^\{\[\(\)\]\}\;\,\?\:\.\=\+\-\*\/\<\>\%\&\|\^\!\~ \n\r\t]+)/g;
var my_capture = ???
```

How do I make it so that the above snippet would result in my_capture == "++cool"?

Comment: You can directly manipulate [`regex.lastIndex`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex)

Comment: ah, well combining setting .lastIndex and removing /g just about does it, thanks

Comment: You can use `src.substr(idx)` to get the part of `src` starting from that index.